# Computing collisions of a rectangle with path lines

Tags: c#, path, xna, collision

I've been looking for samples and tutorials, but I can't find anything specific.

I am making a 2D XNA C# Game and I want to detect the final position of the player when it reaches one or more path lines, so it won't cross them.

The player is made of a collision rectangle, the path lines are all segments. So basically I have the player's collision rectangle and the next player's position collision rectangle. If the next player's position collides to path lines, I want to find the maximum displacement the player can suffer.

The image shows more or less what I want to do:

[image: Picture]

I want to find the position of the red rectangle.

Does anyone have any algorithm, solution or any link that could help me? Could be even a sample.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why are you using rectangles not circles?

Comment: @piotr Auguscik Could be a precision issue.

Comment: Just asking, with circles such tasks are easier :)

Comment: I need to use rectangles because my player is a character, a person. Using a circle wouldn't make sense at all.

Comment: You could make him a snowman!  I can't believe XNA doesn't provide native collision detection for 2D sprites, that's shocking.  Maybe this might have an example?  http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_rectangle

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, unfortunately it won't solve my problem. I know how to calculate the collisions, the problem is to calculate the maximum position, maybe I am thinking the wrong way, but I can't find one single sample on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have the means to check whether a specific collision box contains a collision or not, I would recommend doing a sort of binary search between the player's current position and the collision box:  pick a point halfway between your collision and the previous known non-collision box.  Test again with this new collision box.  If it's not a collision, pick a point halfway between this point and the known collision box, otherwise pick a point halfway backwards.  Repeat until you have found a non-colliding box at a level of accuracy you are satisfied with (say, on the order of 1 to 2 pixels).  With only a handful of tests, you should be able to find such a point.

Comment: Thanks for the response. By the way, do you think this method will work fast enough? Do you know any faster way of doing this?

Comment: You're welcome.  I was thinking about performance as well, and this is probably not a particularly fast way of doing it, but it should only ever be active when a collision is already about to occur.  Depending on the nature of your game, as long as the speed of the player is not too large, you shouldn't need more than say 5 or so tests to get a satisfactory position, which is a small number considering that you are probably doing collision checks at every frame in any case.  If nothing else, it could be a reference implementation that you can use as a base for optimisation.

Comment: As for faster alternatives, I think that would really depend on your game's mechanics and the implementation of the collision checks.  Perhaps by doing the collision checks a bit more smartly, you can get some info about where the collision is.  For example, once you have a collision, you could re-test with smaller sub-rectangles to see where the collision is.  This information may give you a quick way to work out how far you need to move back the player, but this mechanism would work on some assumptions, which I can't easily make about your game.

Comment: Thanks once again Daniel. I did like you said and it works fast enough. I also restricted the precision tests to the initially collided objects only, so it won't test every object in-game after looking for the closest place.